# How to Show Texture on Unity3D using GL function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to show an image to a GL.QUADS. But nothing but a black rect show on the screen. How can I fix it.

Here is my script code and I add the component to MainCamera.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public Material mat;
    void OnPostRender() {
        if (!mat) {
            Debug.LogError("Please Assign a material on the inspector");
            return;
        }
        GL.PushMatrix();
        mat.SetPass(1);
        GL.LoadOrtho();
        GL.Begin(GL.QUADS);
        GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(0.25F, 0.25F, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
        GL.Vertex3(0.25F, 0.75F, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
        GL.Vertex3(0.75F, 0.75F, 0);
        GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(0.75F, 0.25F, 0);
        GL.End();
        GL.PopMatrix();
    }
}
```

I created a custom material named 'CrossHairMaterial' using 'standard' shader:
[image]

[image]

Finally it showed a black rectangle.
[image]

Comment: Is your custom `Material` attached to the `Quad`?

Comment: may not. But how to do it?

Comment: @Hristo Doesn't need to do that. This is not a model/mesh file. This is constructed from OpenGL. Take a look at the code once more.

Comment: @Programmer okay so he just needs to attach his script to the quad?

Comment: I'm confused, What does the _MyGlDraw_ script do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity's [`GL`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.html) API requires vertex shader to work. The default standard shader that is used when new material is created will not work because it's not a vertex shader.

Any vertex shader in Unity should also work.

**First of all, change `mat.SetPass(1);` to `mat.SetPass(0);`.**

*These are the supported Shaders:*

**1**.Particles --> VertexLit Blended.

**2**.Unlit-->Color

**3**.Unlit-->Texture

**4**.Unlit-->Transparent

Lagacy Shaders that should work:

**5**.Legacy Shaders-->Transparent-->VertexLit.

**6**.Legacy Shaders-->VertexLit.

I recommend you use **#2**,**#3** or **#4** depending on if you need Texture or Transparency in the material.

Test with Unlit-->Texture:

[image]